# pick up rental car from Amtrak station in Schenectady NY?

Tags: rental, amtrak

I've only travelled by Amtrak a couple of times. A big catch seems to be that few stations have rental car places. I'm planning a trip to Schenectady NY. Amtrak's web site talks about discounts they arrange with local car rental places, but then they have a map showing them all several miles from the station. How do you get from the train station to the car rental place? Will the rental places pick you up? Is there a shuttle bus? Do I need to find a taxi? Or what?

Comment: In a city the size of Schenectady, it wouldn't surprise me if the (traditional) cab drivers knew the train schedules and waited for fares near the train station around the time of the trains' arrivals.  That's speculation on my part, though, based on my experiences in other similarly sized northeastern towns.

Answer (score 2):

According to [their website](https://www.enterprise.com/en/car-rental/locations/us/ny/schenectady-24h6.html), Enterprise in Schenectady offers a "free pick-up service…at non-airport locations during normal business hours." They further advise that you must call the local office at the number on that website to arrange the pickup, which seems like an especially good idea, as it's worth checking to confirm if the service may be modified or unavailable due to the covid-19 pandemic.

Comment: Note that Enterprise has used "We'll pick you up" as an advertising slogan [since the late '90s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0d_B9dUUKsg);  it's a big part of their brand at this point.